# How can I upload multiple files via SFTP in Spring Batch using ItemWriter with Upload bean injection?

Tags: spring-batch

Spring batch Itemwriter : Upload multiple files via SFTP . How to?
I am trying to inject a Upload bean in my Spring batch ItemWriter and need to upload multiple Files.
I am able to upload only single file.

The upload tasklet I have been given has a single Resournce and does not support multiple files:

public class SftpUploadTasklet implements Tasklet, InitializingBean {

```
private Resource localFileResource;
```

...
...

...
}